# Using Dictionary Data Type in Github Actions

Tags: json, github-actions

Which tricks do you know for using something like dictionary in Github Workflow without reading external files?
I try to create something like this:

```
{
  "clusters01": ["cluster-eu","cluster-us","cluster-au"],
  "clusters02": ["cluster-eu","cluster-au"]
}
```

And I need to check if any key exists in that dictionary and get a list from its value and loop through the elements.

In documentation I saw *object-filters*, but didn't understand what it was about? https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#object-filters

Comment: Did you check matrix https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/using-a-matrix-for-your-jobs ? Not sure how exactly you want to use it though.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is just to use a matrix, you could read and parse some file, and put the result in a matrix.

```
jobs:
  matrix-clusters:
    name: "set matrix of selected cluster"
    outputs:
      matrix-one: ${{ steps.set-matrix.outputs.matrix-one }}
      matrix-stop-all: ${{ steps.set-matrix.outputs.matrix-stop-all }}
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - id: set-matrix
        run: |
          TASK_ONE=$(jq -c --join-output \
          '[to_entries[]|select(.value.env=="${{ github.event.inputs.choice }}")|.value]' \
          .github/workflows/envs/${{ github.event.inputs.cluster_env || 'stg' }}.json)
          echo "matrix-one=$TASK_ONE" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
          TASK_STOP_ALL=$(jq -c --join-output \
           '[to_entries[]|select(.value.skipgroupstop!=true)|.value]' \
          .github/workflows/envs/${{ github.event.inputs.cluster_env || 'stg' }}.json)
          echo "matrix-stop-all=$TASK_STOP_ALL" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
```